# If F is convex and lower semicontinuous in norm, then F is weakly lower semicontinuous

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have to prove the following statement:

If $F$ is convex and lower semicontinuous in norm, then $F$ is weakly lower semicontinuous.

Comment: $F$ is weakly lower semicontinuous iff its lower level sets $S_\alpha=\{x: F(x)\leq \alpha\}$ are weakly closed. But this is true, since they are closed (because $F$ is lower semicontinuous in norm) and convex.